# Not only get duplicates from array, but need as well index of the duplicates

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have the following array:

```
Driver[] predictions = new Driver[6];
predictions[0] = new Driver(10, "Michael Schumacher");
predictions[1] = new Driver(10, "Michael Schumacher");
predictions[2] = new Driver(9, "Fernando Alonso");
predictions[3] = new Driver(8, "Jensen Button");
predictions[4] = new Driver(7, "Felipe Massa");
predictions[5] = new Driver(6, "Giancarlo Fisichella");
```

I want to get all the duplicates - The name once, and then the positions (index) where the duplicates are. So, in this case I want to get "Michael Schumacher" and the positions 1 and 2 (index 0 and 1).

Can this be done in one go, or do I need to consider other options? I just read on DotNetPearls that IndexOf is pretty slow compared to having your own logic.

```
var driversSelectedMoreThanOnceAndTheirPositions = predictions.Select((driver, index) => new { driver, index })
.GroupBy(item => item.driver.Name)
.Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(a => (a.index + 1)).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To utilize linq for this, you could write something like the following, which uses an overload of `Select` that allows you to get the element index and then performs a `GroupBy` operation.

```
var query = 
 predictions.Select((driver, index) => new { driver, index })
 .GroupBy(item => item.driver.Name)
 .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
 .Select(grp => new { Name = grp.Key, Indexes = grp.Select(item => item.index) });
```

This will result in a sequence of anonymous-typed objects with the properties

```
class Anon
{
    public string Name;
    public IEnumerable<int> Indexes;
}
```

Which you could use as in

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    foreach (int index in item.Indexes)
        Console.WriteLine(index);
}
```

You can, of course, change the way you group to get the entire driver object.

Comment: Great answer! Only thing I would change is some sort of grp.CountGreaterThan(1) instead of grp.Count() > 1 to avoid counting the whole enumerable?

Comment: @fparadis2, Perhaps you could do something like `grp.Skip(1).Any()` if you truly have some massive groups, but that's a later optimization, I do believe.

Comment: Oh, wow, hadn't thought of that. Anyways, your code was the code that got me pushed in the right direction (I posted the code). What is this thing with CountGreaterThan?

Comment: @Garth, that would be a hypothetical method you would have to define in order to use it, as it presently does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will give you a dictionary keyed by driver's name, with a value of all their positions in the original array.  It will also give you a unique list (HashSet) containing only those driver names which occurred more than once in the orginal array.

```
      Driver[] predictions = new Driver[6];
      predictions[0] = new Driver(10, "Michael Schumacher");
      predictions[1] = new Driver(10, "Michael Schumacher");
      predictions[2] = new Driver(9, "Fernando Alonso");
      predictions[3] = new Driver(8, "Jensen Button");
      predictions[4] = new Driver(7, "Felipe Massa");
      predictions[5] = new Driver(6, "Giancarlo Fisichella");

      Dictionary<string, List<int>> indicies = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
      HashSet<string> driversWithDups = new HashSet<string>();
      for (int i=0; i<predictions.Length; i++)
      {
        Driver eachDriver = predictions[i];
        if (indicies.ContainsKey(eachDriver.Name))
        {
          indicies[eachDriver.Name].Add(i);
          driversWithDups.Add(eachDriver.Name);
        }
        else
        {
          indicies[eachDriver.Name] = new List<int>() {i};
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the obvious definition of the Driver class, this should give you what you want:

```
        Driver[] predictions = new Driver[6];
        predictions[0] = new Driver(10, "Michael Schumacher");
        predictions[1] = new Driver(10, "Michael Schumacher");
        predictions[2] = new Driver(9, "Fernando Alonso");
        predictions[3] = new Driver(8, "Jensen Button");
        predictions[4] = new Driver(7, "Felipe Massa");
        predictions[5] = new Driver(6, "Giancarlo Fisichella");

        var ds = predictions.Select((driver, i) => new { Name = driver.Name, Index = i })
                            .GroupBy(a => a.Name, a => a.Index);
```

Comment: Yes, this was indeed in the right direction. Anthony Pegram posted something similar which I added upon a bit. I put the code up in my original post.